# Постраничная навигация Ms Sql

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 10 FROM news;
```

Куда подставлять LIMIT и OFFSET ?

Answer (score 1):

В TSQL отсутствует LIMIT. TOP вместо него.

OFFSET есть в MSSQL Server 2011 и выше. Пример использования: `SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news.id OFFSET (10) Rows;`

Comment: у меня Server 2008 ((

Comment: Тогда без OFFSET обойтись придется.

Comment: а пагинацию как тогда замутить?(((

Comment: Нормальная пагинация введена в MSSQL Server 2012.

Для более ранних версий:

    WITH page_set AS (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <ordering>) AS [row_number],
        x, y, z
      FROM
        news
      WHERE
        <search-clauses>
    ) SELECT
      *
    FROM
      page_set 
    WHERE
      [row_number] BETWEEN a AND b

Comment: а с 2008 мигрировать на 2012 можно без потерь?)

Comment: Вроде как да, с 2008 на 2012 безболезненно можно мигрировать. Но назад (2012 -> 2008) отсутствие проблем не гарантирую.

Comment: а как примерно это сделать? не подскажешь?)

Comment: Выполнить detach базы данных в SQL Server 2008 и ее attach в SQL Server 2012.

Detach:

    EXEC sp_detach_db '<database_name>', 'true';

Attach:

    CREATE DATABASE <database_name> 
        ON (FILENAME = '<full_db_file_name.mdf>'), 
        (FILENAME = '<full_db_file_name.ldf') 
        FOR ATTACH;

Или средствами [MSSQL Server Management Studio][1].

[1]: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Впервые сталкиваюсь с этим ms sql server) мне надо скачать 2012, и все заработает? точнее offset будет работать?) сорри за глупый вопрос)

Comment: Если вы поставите SQL Server 2012 на ОС с установленным SQL Server 2008, то у вас будет два instance SQL Server. Естественно, для работы с offset Вам необходимо будет задействовать SQL Server 2012, а не SQL Server 2008.

Comment: а где это сделать?(

Comment: Что именно сделать? Скачать SQL Server 2012?

Comment: скачал, устанавливаю) как задействовать 2012?)

Comment: Если со сторонней программы, то в connection string указать параметры подключения именно к SQL Server 2012.
Если для администрирования БД, то рекомендую использовать SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (идет в комплекте с SQL Server 2012).